# Flask generate dynamic table where number of rows and columns depends on number of elements in the list

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Dear stackoverflow users,

I am creating a website with flask as a backend. It will fetch some data from different systems e.x. jenkins.
one of the "data packs" will be a list of Jenkins jobs
the main .py file will include route to a page

```
@app.route("/simplejenkins")
def simple_jenkins():
    return render_template('simplejenkins.html', job_list=job_list)
```

and the simplejenkins.html will iterate over the job_list and list them

```
{% for job in jobs_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ job }}</td>
    <td>
        <p>Successful!</p>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

the idea is that the number of elements in the list will change over time.
and I want to put them in the table - each element (job) in different cell. And let's say I want to have 6 columns (depends on the screen resolution, but let's ignore this for now). So in case of 44 jobs I should have 7 full rows and 2 more job in 8th row.

and my question is, how to achieve this?

the script below generates a table with dynamic number of rows and columns but how to populate the cells using jinja?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset=utf-8 /> 
<title>Dynamic Table</title> 
<script>
window.onload = createTable;
function createTable()
{
rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
cn = window.prompt("Input number of columns",1);

 for(var r=0;r<parseInt(rn,10);r++)
  {
   var x=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(r);
   for(var c=0;c<parseInt(cn,10);c++)  
    {
     var y=  x.insertCell(c);
     y.innerHTML="Row-"+r+" Column-"+c; 
    }
   }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
body {margin: 30px;} 
</style>  
</head>
<body> 
<table id="myTable" border="1"> 
</table><form> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i don't expect full solution of course, a link to existing similar case should be more than enough... somehow i cannot find one
thanks in advance for help
regards
Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

1. To use that JS script all you need is an ajax call, once the page is ready, the ajax call will retrieve the data (jobs) from your flask route as JSON data and insert it in the table, with no need for jinja at all.
2. Or if it's not necessary for you to use a table, you can use the inline display in your frontend where your jobs will float next to each other as long as there is space, otherwise they will fall to the next line, you will loop over those jobs exactly as you did, but instead of having rows and cells you will have divs or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

would you mind trying this ?

```
<table>
{% max_columns = 6 %}
{% interval = jobs_list|length / max_columns }
{% rows = interval|int + 1 }    # +1 for the last/incomplete row

{% for p in range(rows) %}
<tr>
    {% for n in range(max_columns) %}
        {% cell_pos = (p * max_columns) + n }
        <td>{{ jobs_list[cell_pos] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```